# Create new page option in site pages library does use the default custom page template in SharePoint Modern site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages

I have created a custom page template in modern SharePoint online site and set that to default page template. While trying to create a page from NEW>PAGE within the site pages library, it does not create the page with the template I have created.

Also, I have a button in another page which has below link, does not use the custom template I have created.

https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/portal/_layouts/15/CreateSitePage.aspx

Kindly, kelp me on this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is custom scripting enabled? https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/unable-to-add-custom-template-to-a-new-modern-site-connected-to/m-p/722769

Comment: already enabled.
I am expecting if there could be any query string that may help here.

Comment: Try using PnP PowerShell: https://pnp.github.io/powershell/
Then you can create a new page with a specific template. 
`$page = Add-PnPPage -Name "PageName" -LayoutType Home -Template "TemplateName"; Set-PnPPage -Identity $page -Publish`